# Access "Remote config" of second project

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-remote-config

We have provision to access multiple Firebase database,

```
// Retrieve my other app.
FirebaseApp app = FirebaseApp.getInstance("secondary");
// Get the database for the other app.
FirebaseDatabase secondaryDatabase = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance(app);
```

In same way, is there any way to access my second project Remote config ??

Ref:
[Accessing the Databases from two different Firebase projects](https://firebase.googleblog.com/2016/12/working-with-multiple-firebase-projects-in-an-android-app.html)

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, there is no such mechanism for Remote Config.  Remote Config is deeply tied to Firebase Analytics, which is also limited to one instance per app.  Remote Config uses Analytics to know some things about the user, for the purpose of determining what value they're supposed to get for a particular parameter. Therefore, you have to accept that the default project's reckoning of "user" is the one that Remote Config is also going to use.

Comment: I've spent hours trying to understand why remote config just uses default  local values and doesn't really fetch anything. Life saving answer.Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

I don't know exactly when did Firebase add this api, but it seems they have added a method to return a `RemoteConfig` referring to `FirebaseApp` since last answer:

```
// Retrieve secondary app.
FirebaseApp app = FirebaseApp.getInstance("secondary");
// Get the remote config for the other app.
FirebaseRemoteConfig secondaryRemoteConfig = Firebase.remoteConfig(app);
// Or another way
// FirebaseRemoteConfig secondaryRemoteConfig = FirebaseRemoteConfig.getInstance(app);
```

**CAUTION:** You still need to, of course, fetch this remote config before use it.

```
secondRemoteConfig.fetch().addOnSuccessListener {
        Log.d("RemoteConfig", "Secondary: finished fetch, ready to use.")
    };
```

Also, note that if you call `fetchAndActivate` and observe the result instead, it will return success with a result Boolean `false` in most situations -- since you already got one activated remote config (in my guess).

Just write down here to help future googlers ;)